# ssh - private key file requires \n at the end of file or cause "Load key id_rsa invalid format"

Tags: 20.04, openssh

## Question

Has OpenSSH introduced a change that requires `\n` at the end of the private key file (id_rsa)? Previously I was on Ubuntu 18.04 and I believe `id_rsa` without `\n` at the end of the file was working. Now on Ubuntu 20.04, ssh does not work if `id_rsa` does not have `\n` at the end of the file.

```
$ diff id_rsa.bak.od id_rsa.od 
163,164c163,164
< 000a20       K   E   Y   -   -   -   -   -
< 000a29
---
> 000a20       K   E   Y   -   -   -   -   -  \n
> 000a2a
```

Without the `\n`, it causes the error.

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu
Load key "/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
```

## Environment

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Having a newline at the end of each line *is* what makes it a line (and a file a text file) [by definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446241/70524). So, when you say "I believe id_rsa without \n at the end of the file was working," I strongly recommend you verify that using a VM or a container.

Comment: FWIW some of my private key files go back to 2017, and all of them have a `\n` at the end.